# how to use model function result in controller by codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a function in Codeignite model that return just a row. This bellow code is my function in Codeigniter model:

```
public function Load_Home_Page_Theme(){
    $CMD = "call load_home_page_theme()";
    $query = $this->db->query($CMD);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Now I want to use a field value that this function returned in a controller function like this:

```
public function Home(){
        $this->load->model("Admin/Admin_getdata");
        $data["HomePageTheme"] = $this->Admin_getdata->Load_Home_Page_Theme();
        $this->load->view("User/Header", $data);
        $data["AdsData"] = $this->Admin_getdata->Load_Ads_Data($data["HomePageTheme"]["home_ads_quantity"]);
        $this->load->view("User/Home", $data);
        $this->load->view("User/Footer");
    }
```

But when I run this code, this error will shown:

> Message: Undefined index: home_ads_quantity

How I can solve it?
Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:::

Model

```
 public function Load_Home_Page_Theme(){
    $CMD = "call load_home_page_theme()";
    $query = $this->db->query($CMD);
    return $query->row();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function Home(){
        $this->load->model("Admin/Admin_getdata");
        $HomePageTheme = $this->Admin_getdata->Load_Home_Page_Theme();
        $data['HomePageTheme']=$HomePageTheme;
        $this->load->view("User/Header", $data);
        $data["AdsData"] = $this->Admin_getdata->Load_Ads_Data($HomePageTheme->home_ads_quantity);
        $this->load->view("User/Home", $data);
        $this->load->view("User/Footer");
    }
```